# Select lines having count greater than x and less than y using linux command

Tags: linux, awk

I have the following file:

```
1,A 
2,B
3,C
10000,D
20,E
4000,F
```

---

I want to select the lines having a count greater than **10** and less than **5000**. the output should be **E** and **F**. In C++ or any other language is a piece of cake. I really wanted to know how can I do it with a linux command.

---

I tried the following command

```
awk -F ',' '{$1 >= 10 && $1 < 5000} { count++ } END { print $1,$2}' test.txt
```

But it is only givine 4000,F.

Comment: head to http://awk.info/?Learn to learn about awk. It is a highly useful tool to have in your kit.

Comment: I started using it a couple of days ago. Instead of writing a BIGG code I just need to use this simple command. thank u @glennjackman. I am very new but it's a really important tool.

Comment: You mistook action block delimiters `{...}` for condition delimiters `(...).`. Change `{$1 >= 10 && $1 < 5000}` to `($1 >= 10 && $1 < 5000)`. It still won't do what you want but it'll be awk syntax and you can see @Kent's answer for the full solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just do:

```
awk -F',' '$1 >= 10 && $1 < 5000' test.txt
```

- you put boolean check in `{....}`, and don't use the result at all. it doesn't make any sense. You should do either `{if(...) ...}` or `booleanExpression{do...}`
- useless `count++`
- you have only `print` statement in `END` so only last line was printed out.

Your script does actually:

```
print the last line of the test.txt, no matter what it is.
```